# How many drives can I safely lose in a RAID-10 array?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, hard-drive-failure, raid-10

In a 4-drive RAID-10 setup, how many drives can I "safely" lose before the data becomes unrecoverable? It's a bit unclear to me whether the setup provides one drive or two drives worth of redundancy.

Is the redundancy of RAID-01 different or the same as RAID-10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RAID-10 consists of a stripe of mirrors. As long as one disk in a mirror is functional, you're fine.

If in the below example you lost Disk 0 and 1, you would lose data. If you lost Disk 0 and 2, your data would still be accessible from the mirrored stripe.

[image]

<sub>[Picture from Wikipedia.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RAID_10_01.svg)</sub>

Since RAID-01 is a mirror of stripes, it offers the same redundancy. The disks are just logically ordered in a different way.

In practice, this means that you should already be warned when one disk fails, because the second disk failing may have a one in three chance of being the one that makes you lose data.

Comment: So, I guess you could say, "**RAID-10** provides **1.66** drives worth of redundancy"? ;-)

Comment: You know, if I was in marketing, I'd say, "*Up to* 2 drives" :)

Comment: That's the _exact_ phrase I keep hearing thrown around (and causing me confusion), which is the reason I opened this question.

Comment: "it offers the same redundancy" only with 4 disks. For any Array with more than 4 disks, see this post for some "maths" on why to use 10 not 01: https://serverfault.com/questions/145319/is-there-a-difference-between-raid-10-10-and-raid-01-01

Comment: Yes, a 10-disk array supports the loss of "upto 5 disks" in any configuration. (One whole Group in case of Raid-01, or one disk of each group in case of Raid-10) But the Propability to actually LOOSE a critical disk is way higher for 01: After the first disk is lost, 5/9 disks have the chance to kill your Raid 01 (Any Disk of the second Raid-0-Group). In a Raid 10, only 1/9 disks has the capability to do this. (The second disk in the very same Raid-1-Group)